# Can a regular expression be any string from the language described by it?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Is it possible to have a regular expression from a language (that has strings of infinite length) which it describes ?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.
Could you try rephrasing it, or perhaps add an example of what you mean?

Comment: A language can be defined by a regular expression iff it is regular.

Comment: No language contains strings of infinite length.

Comment: Do you mean a language $L$ consisting of strings, at least one of which, $s_i$ interpreted as a regular expresssion exactly describes $L$?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. However "a language (that has strings of infinite length)" cannot exist. By definition a language only contains words of finite length.

Let $\Sigma$ be a (finite) alphabet and $\epsilon$ denote the empty word.
A language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma^*$ is defined as $\Sigma^* = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Sigma^i$, $\Sigma^0 = \{ \epsilon \}$, and $\Sigma^i = \{xy : x \in \Sigma^{i-1}, y \in \Sigma\}$ for $i>0$.

As you can see, a string of infinite length does not belong to any $\Sigma^i$ and therefore it belongs to neither $\Sigma^*$ nor to any of its subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean, but a is an element of L(a). Actually the only element of L(a). (while a* is not an element of L(a*) because none of the elements contain the symbol *).